# Use a user defined vim command inside another user defined vim command

Tags: vim, vi, neovim

I am trying to have to custom commands in vim as follows:
The first command just runs a bash script. this works fine on its own.

```
:command Build :!./build-linux.sh
```

Now I want to use this command in another such as this:

```
:command BuildAndDebug :Build | :call vimspector#Launch()
```

This command is supposed to run the bash script and then launch a debugger.
When I try to do this, I get this error back:

```
E488: Trailing characters: :Build | :call vimspector#Launch()
```

I can't seem to find the trailing characters here. I suspect the `:Build` is the cause of this because it does not know where the command ends. However I can't seem to get it to work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `-bar` attribute to your command definition if you want to be able to "chain" other commands after it with `|`:

```
:command -bar Build :!./build-linux.sh
```

This is described in chapter 40 of the user manual: `:help usr_40`, and documented under `:help :command-bar`.